# Cassandra Verifying Bulk Import

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have a Cassandra cluster up and running with 5 nodes.

I created a keyspace with replication_factor=3 and created a table within.

I used `cqlsh` to bulk load a CSV into my table.

I get this message after loading:

```
355637 rows imported from 1 file
```

However, when I connect to the cluster with `cqlsh` and execute

```
select count(*) from my_keyspaces.my_table;
```

I only get

```
 count
--------
 122715
```

The way my schema is set up, there are actually only 6 rows (one for each device), using Cassandra's wide rows.

However, `cqlsh` exposes these as rows to make life easier.

My question is, why does `count(*)` not return an accurate number, and furthermore, why is the number it did return extremely close to `1/3` of my expected number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good chance you are accidentally upserting.  This will happen if you have multiple rows in the CSV that have the same primary key.

Comment: Sigh, this is correct. I thought had done my due dilligence but apparently not!

Answer (score 0):

Besides @brandon reply (that's right in most of the cases), you can also set upper limit in your query like select count(*) from cf limit 1000000 or use nodetool cfstats for more insights.